# Errorbundles after parsing with megaparsec

Tags: haskell, megaparsec

I currently have a working parser in megaparsec, where I build an AST for my program. I now want to do some weeding operations on my AST, while being able to use the same kind of pretty errors as the parser. While this stage is after parsing, I'm wondering if there are general practices for megaparsec in doing so. Is there a way for me to extract every line and comment (used in the bundle) and add it to each item in my AST? Is there any other way that people tackle this problem?

Apologies in advance if this sounds open ended, but I'm mainly wondering is there are some better ideas than getting the line numbers and creating bundles myself. I'm still new to haskell so I haven't been able to navigate properly through all the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was answered by the megaparsec developer [here](https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/issues/343#issuecomment-460415982).

To summarize, parsers have a `getOffset` function that returns the current char index. You can use that along with an initial `PosState` to create an error bundle which you can later pretty print.

I have a sample project [within the github thread](https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/issues/343#issuecomment-460434723), and pasted again here:

```
module TestParser where

import           Data.List.NonEmpty as NonEmpty
import qualified Data.Maybe         as Maybe
import qualified Data.Set           as Set
import           Data.Void
import           Parser
import           Text.Megaparsec

data Sample
  = Test Int
         String
  | TestBlock [Sample]
  | TestBlank
  deriving (Show, Eq)

sampleParser :: Parser Sample
sampleParser = do
  l <- many testParser
  return $ f l
  where
    f []  = TestBlank
    f [s] = s
    f p   = TestBlock p

testParser :: Parser Sample
testParser = do
  offset <- getOffset
  test <- symbol "test"
  return $ Test offset test

fullTestParser :: Parser Sample
fullTestParser = baseParser testParser

testParse :: String -> Maybe (ParseErrorBundle String Void)
testParse input =
  case parse (baseParser sampleParser) "" input of
    Left e -> Just e
    Right x -> do
      (offset, msg) <- testVerify x
      let initialState =
            PosState
              { pstateInput = input
              , pstateOffset = 0
              , pstateSourcePos = initialPos ""
              , pstateTabWidth = defaultTabWidth
              , pstateLinePrefix = ""
              }
      let errorBundle =
            ParseErrorBundle
              { bundleErrors = NonEmpty.fromList [TrivialError offset Nothing Set.empty]
                            -- ^ A collection of 'ParseError's that is sorted by parse error offsets
              , bundlePosState = initialState
                            -- ^ State that is used for line\/column calculation
              }
      return errorBundle

-- Sample verify; throw an error on the second test key
testVerify :: Sample -> Maybe (Int, String)
testVerify tree =
  case tree of
    TestBlock [_, Test a _, _] -> Just (a, "Bad")
    _                          -> Nothing

testMain :: IO ()
testMain = do
  testExample "test test test"
  putStrLn "Done"

testExample :: String -> IO ()
testExample input =
  case testParse input of
    Just error -> putStrLn (errorBundlePretty error)
    Nothing    -> putStrLn "pass"
```

Some parts are from other files, but the important parts are in the code.